# Delete and Insert takes long time in MySQL(InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-performance, query-performance

I've set of numbers and to each number in it there are few numbers associated with it. So I store it in a table like this:

```
NUMBERS  ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS
1        3
1        7
1        8
2        11
2        7
7        9
8        13
11       17
14       18
17       11
17       18
```

Thus it's a number which has many associated numbers and vice versa. Both columns are indexed. (Thus enabling me to find number and its associated numbers and vice versa)

My create table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_B` (
  `NUMBERS` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_number_associatednumber_constraint` (`NUMBERS`,`ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS`),
  KEY `fk_AssociatedNumberConstraint` (`ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AssociatedNumberConstraint` FOREIGN KEY (`ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS`) REFERENCES `table_a` (`SRNO`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_NumberConstraint` FOREIGN KEY (`NUMBERS`) REFERENCES `table_a`` (`SRNO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here `TABLE_A` has column `SRNO` which is `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and is *first* column in the table. (As per MySQL manual I haven't defined indexes on `TABLE_B.NUMBERS` and `TABLE_B.ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS` as foreign key constraints defines it automatically)

**PROBLEM:**

Whenever I need to change `ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS` for a number (in `NUMBERS') I just delete existing rows for that number from the table:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_B WHERE NUMBERS= ?
```

and then insert rows for new set of ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (NUMBERS, ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS) VALUES ( ?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), ...
```

However, this takes long time. Especially when in my multi-threaded application I open multiple connections (each per thread) to the database, each running above two queries (but each with different number).

For example, if I open 40 connections, each connection to delete existing and insert 250 new associated numbers, it takes upto 10 to 15 seconds. If I increase number of connections, the time also increases.

**Other Information:**

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';
```

Shows upto 40 threads.

Innodb parameters:

```
innodb_adaptive_flushing, ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm, 10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index, ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay, 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size, 2097152
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval, 5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock, OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog, OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl, OFF
innodb_api_trx_level, 0
innodb_autoextend_increment, 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode, 1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown, OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now, OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename, ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances, 8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort, OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup, OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now, OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size, 1073741824
innodb_change_buffer_max_size, 25
innodb_change_buffering, all
innodb_checksum_algorithm, crc32
innodb_checksums, ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled, OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency, 0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct, 5
innodb_compression_level, 6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max, 50
innodb_concurrency_tickets, 5000
innodb_data_file_path, ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir, 
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache, OFF
innodb_doublewrite, ON
innodb_fast_shutdown, 1
innodb_file_format, Antelope
innodb_file_format_check, ON
innodb_file_format_max, Antelope
innodb_file_per_table, ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout, 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, 2
innodb_flush_method, normal
innodb_flush_neighbors, 1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops, 30
innodb_force_load_corrupted, OFF
innodb_force_recovery, 0
innodb_ft_aux_table, 
innodb_ft_cache_size, 8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print, OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword, ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size, 84
innodb_ft_min_token_size, 3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize, 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit, 2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table, 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree, 2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size, 640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table, 
innodb_io_capacity, 200
innodb_io_capacity_max, 2000
innodb_large_prefix, OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout, 50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog, OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size, 268435456
innodb_log_compressed_pages, ON
innodb_log_file_size, 262144000
innodb_log_files_in_group, 2
innodb_log_group_home_dir, .\
innodb_lru_scan_depth, 1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct, 75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm, 0
innodb_max_purge_lag, 0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay, 0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups, 1
innodb_monitor_disable, 
innodb_monitor_enable, 
innodb_monitor_reset, 
innodb_monitor_reset_all, 
innodb_old_blocks_pct, 37
innodb_old_blocks_time, 1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size, 134217728
innodb_open_files, 300
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only, OFF
innodb_page_size, 16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks, OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size, 300
innodb_purge_threads, 1
innodb_random_read_ahead, OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold, 56
innodb_read_io_threads, 64
innodb_read_only, OFF
innodb_replication_delay, 0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout, OFF
innodb_rollback_segments, 128
innodb_sort_buffer_size, 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay, 6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc, ON
innodb_stats_method, nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata, OFF
innodb_stats_persistent, ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages, 20
innodb_stats_sample_pages, 8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages, 8
innodb_status_output, OFF
innodb_status_output_locks, OFF
innodb_strict_mode, OFF
innodb_support_xa, ON
innodb_sync_array_size, 1
innodb_sync_spin_loops, 30
innodb_table_locks, ON
innodb_thread_concurrency, 0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay, 10000
innodb_undo_directory, .
innodb_undo_logs, 128
innodb_undo_tablespaces, 0
innodb_use_native_aio, OFF
innodb_use_sys_malloc, ON
innodb_version, 5.6.28
innodb_write_io_threads, 16
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is "SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS" output: http://pastebin.com/raw/E3rK4Pu5

**UPDATE2:**

The reason behind this was somewhere else and not actually DB. Some other function in my code was eating lots of CPU causing MySQL (which runs on same machine) to go slow. Thanks for all your answers and help.

Comment: How big is the table?  Do you need `BIGINT`?  Or would `INT UNSIGNED` suffice?

Comment: How fast does it run if you have only, say, 5 threads running?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS`

Comment: Do you really need the FKs?  They _do_ take extra time.

Comment: Table has currently 280213 rows. For six thread it took 0.1 to 2 seconds. For 40 threads it took 3 to 12 seconds. I removed FKs (replaced with single composite index `NUMBERS, ASSOCIATEDNUMBERS`) also tried with INT UNSIGNED without any luck. Here is "SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS" output: http://pastebin.com/raw/E3rK4Pu5

Comment: Hmmm...  Apparently "Thread 3780" is the villain, but it is not obvious what it is doing.  Notice how almost all the threads are waiting for it.

Comment: 7 times as many threads took more than 7x longer -- this says (as does the semaphore waits) that InnoDB is stumbling over itself.  (Alas, I don't see exactly why.)  Use fewer threads to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are acquiring lock on the row/table before deleting/inserting so that's why it is causing you the issue.

Check

```
SELECT * from information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES;
```

Also, check locks on table using

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES  from <database name> where In_use>0
```

and lock type using

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS
```

So when you run the query add these on watch and you can also use tee command to store it in file.

So, there is one more thing that can cause this, although you have indexed the column, but there are limitations to mysql if data Read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html) for limitation.

Read this to install watch http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/22/install-watch-command-on-os-x/  and run watch script with time delay of 1 second and then run mysql queries in watch, if you want to store it in file use tee command and then write output on file. You can tail to get the data in file

Comment: Thanks for this info. Wanted to get output of these in single txt file before each delete/insert so that I'll get to know if table/row was locked. But not sure how to run it through application. There is no info on how Tee can be used through application (not from command line). "select" output can be diverted to txt file using `into outfile` but there are limitations (like it cannot use same text file to append) also SHOW OPEN TABLES output cannot be diverted to file in the same way.

Comment: So, while application was deleting/inserting rows in multiple threads(connections), I ran these queries through command-line quite frequently. But only `show open tables` returned rows occasionally showing number of locks  for `table_b` (under column `in_use`). But locks for those particular rows (being deleted/inserted) are expected isn't it? or (am I interpreting it it incorrectly?). However, `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS` never returned any row.